# I want to save a MP4 Video from array list of frames

Tags: java, android, video, mp4, frames

i want to extract frames from a video and add effect in this frames then i want to save this frames as mp4 Video 
[here is](https://github.com/MuhammadNasser/VideoEffects/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/mondy/videoeffects/MainActivity.java) what i use in my code and it didn't work

ineed help please

Comment: sorry i can't write the code here

Comment: you don't have to "write" the code here, copy paste will do.. we have no idea what input your code has, what errors occur, what happens and what goes wrong ... does it compile? do you get runtime exceptions? ...

Comment: which part of your code exactly is not working?

Comment: @Bhargav
initializeViews return null

Comment: whoa that github link you just gave is a nightmare to read through, code styling is really bad !

Comment: yeah cause i don't know how i use this functions it is the first time i use jcodec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding each frame of a video into an array is bad pratice. An array holds it's values in memory, so every frame you save in that array will be in memory. That will probably lead to an `OutOfMemoryException` as bitmaps are not cheap. If you want to process frames in a video, you should probably use [OpenCV](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/ios/video_processing/video_processing.html)

Comment: but am working on android app

Comment: Then you should use the  [android version of OpenCV](http://opencv.org/platforms/android.html)

Comment: its not what i wanna do :(

Comment: thank you i get it and  am work in it now :) 

but could you answer this question ??